# Elastic search average aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Here is a sample of my code in Kibana:

```
get sample/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

I have put * for lat and lon for the sake of privacy and those numbers won't make any change anyways. Here come the results I received:

```
 {
  "took": 53,
  "timed_out": false,
  "num_reduce_phases": 3,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1293,
    "successful": 1293,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
      },
  "hits": {
    "total": 10937405,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "sample_2016-08-08",
        "_type": "sample",
        "_id": "18-26-55-1470693602000",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "type": "a",
          "company": 18,
          "value": 0,
          "equipment": 26,
          "state": "",
          "location": {
            "lat": *,
            "lon": *
          },
          "sensor": 55,
          "sampled_on": 1470693602000
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "sample_2016-08-08",
        "_type": "sample",
        "_id": "18-26-56-1470693602000",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "type": "a",
          "company": 18,
          "value": 7.436,
          "equipment": 26,
          "state": "",
          "location": {
            "lat": *,
            "lon": *
          },
          "sensor": 56,
          "sampled_on": 1470693602000
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "sample_2016-08-08",
        "_type": "sample",
        "_id": "18-26-57-1470693602000",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "type": "a",
          "company": 18,
          "value": 148.538,
          "equipment": 26,
          "state": "",
          "location": {
            "lat": *,
            "lon": *
          },
          "sensor": 57,
          "sampled_on": 1470693602000
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "sample_2016-08-08",
        "_type": "sample",
        "_id": "18-26-59-1470693602000",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "type": "a",
          "company": 18,
          "value": 0.196,
          "equipment": 26,
          "state": "",
          "location": {
            "lat": *,
            "lon": *
          },
          "sensor": 59,
          "sampled_on": 1470693602000
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "sample_2016-08-08",
        "_type": "sample",
        "_id": "18-26-63-1470693708000",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "type": "a",
          "company": 18,
          "value": 31.3,
          "equipment": 26,
          "state": "",
          "location": {
            "lat": *,
            "lon": *
          },
          "sensor": 63,
          "sampled_on": 1470693708000
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "sample_2016-08-08",
        "_type": "sample",
        "_id": "18-26-65-1470693708000",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "type": "a",
          "company": 18,
          "value": 25.6,
          "equipment": 26,
          "state": "",
          "location": {
            "lat": *,
            "lon": *
          },
          "sensor": 65,
          "sampled_on": 1470693708000
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "sample_2016-08-08",
        "_type": "sample",
        "_id": "18-26-62-1470693708000",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "type": "a",
          "company": 18,
          "value": 0.255,
          "equipment": 26,
          "state": "",
          "location": {
            "lat": *,
            "lon": *
          },
          "sensor": 62,
          "sampled_on": 1470693708000
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "sample_2016-08-08",
        "_type": "sample",
        "_id": "18-26-63-1470693809000",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "type": "a",
          "company": 18,
          "value": 31.3,
          "equipment": 26,
          "state": "",
          "location": {
            "lat": *,
            "lon": *
          },
          "sensor": 63,
          "sampled_on": 1470693809000
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "sample_2016-08-08",
        "_type": "sample",
        "_id": "18-26-64-1470693809000",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "type": "a",
          "company": 18,
          "value": 25.9,
          "equipment": 26,
          "state": "",
          "location": {
            "lat": *,
            "lon": *
          },
          "sensor": 64,
          "sampled_on": 1470693809000
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "sample_2016-08-08",
        "_type": "sample",
        "_id": "18-26-65-1470693809000",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "type": "a",
          "company": 18,
          "value": 25.6,
          "equipment": 26,
          "state": "",
          "location": {
            "lat": *,
            "lon": *
          },
          "sensor": 65,
          "sampled_on": 1470693809000
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

"sampled_on" represents time. Each "sensor" sends a new "value" like every few seconds. I would like to receive the following result and I want it to be in 1 query:
For every "sensor" display the average "value" it has reported in 30-min intervals from beginnning to now .
Here is an example:

sensor 1

the oldest one
...
...
14 Jan 2009
2:30 pm - 3:00 pm
average value:5
...
18 Feb 2012
3:10 am - 3:40 am
average value:4
...
the newest one

sensor 2

the oldest one
...
...
01 Jan 2011
5:30 pm - 6:00 pm
average value:5
...
03 Feb 2012
7:20 am - 7:50 am
average value:4
...
the newest one

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please show the average query you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

This is my example query that I made in Kibana and than I clipped the request. This means that some parts are unnecessary and I had to rename some fields since I made a similar request on my own records.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "sensor",
        "size": 500,
        "order": {
          "1": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "1": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that the 'aggs.2.terms.size' is set to 500 which may clip some results if you have more sensors.